# Error: Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379:connection refused

Tags: node.js, redis

The detailed installation guide to install Redis on Mac

Hello Everyone,

I recently stumbled upon a YT video on Redis Crash Course by "BRAD" in Traversy Media Channel(https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC29ju8bIPH5as8OGnQzwJyA). Below are the following that I got stuck in while Installing Redis.

- I was unable to download Redis through CLI i.e. wget
  https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.6.tar.gz and note, I
  used curl as wget was not functional.
- I was unable to start the Redis-Cli and it tortured me with an Error:
  Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379:connection refused not
  connected> Below are the steps that I followed to install and run
  successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution]Problem statement 1:

Instead of downloading through CLI, I tried downloading the "tar.gz" file directly. Downloaded the stable version 6.2.6 and then followed the below CLI commands.

$ tar xzf redis-6.2.6.tar.gz $ cd redis-6.2.6 $ make

This made the job easy to make a binary. Post which, I followed the Redis documentation to run the redis-server. And, it worked fine.

[Solution]Problem statement 2:

As I said, I was unable to run the redis-cli even though, I was able to successfully run the redis-server. I tried several websites and StackOverflow to understand the concept behind the error. That's when I realized the redis-server and redis-client are two separate executable files/process so to make the redis-client work, you should keep in mind that the redis-server should run either in background or in other terminal.

Note, if you're executing the redis-server in the same terminal, then make sure to run the server in the background using the below command.

redis-server --daemonize yes

This should solve the problem, now try using the redis-cli. It will work perfectly.

Now, you can see port 6379 with the localhost IP, make a test PING and confirm it is connected.